# Node.js: First Character is undefined in fs.createReadStream

Tags: node.js, node-streams

I am trying to read streams from a simple text file and logging all the characters once the Read Streams gets completed but strangely every time the first character is always undefined.
I am not sure if I am missing anything while reading streams from text file.

`

```
const fs= require('fs');
const readStreams = fs.createReadStream('text.txt');
let data;
readStreams.on('data',(dataChunks)=>{
  data+=dataChunks;
}
);

readStreams.on('end',() =>{
    console.log(data);
});
```

`
[image: Terminal Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have initialized  data with undefined that's getting appended to stream , assigning empty string will solve your problem

```
let data = '';
```

Alternate solution would be using pipe operation instead of data

```
readStreams.pipe(process.stdout);
```